# Bad Company Feedback Prior to Job Interview

Tags: interviewing

I was recently contacted for a job interview.  While telling a close friend about the job interview she informed me that another friend of hers used to have this exact same job at this particular company and had nothing nice to say about it.  This friend indicated poor management communication, constant travel and previous to her, high turn over plus and a few other thing that has kind of put me on the defensive.

This person had this job 4 years ago, so I understand things could have changed, BUT I'd still like to find a way to address some of the things she said.  Any suggestions on approaching these topics?

Comment: Related: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/12516/325

Answer (score 4):

Just ask the questions in the interview; "How much travel is involved", "What is the level of company staff turnover", "What is the management style". Use the negative review as a shopping list of things to point at, but don't use it to exclude yourself from the position - things change.