# Should I join a company if its reviews on glassdoor etc are not very good?

Tags: professionalism, job-search, job-offer, unprofessional-behavior, discrimination

I am offered a job from the company as a web developer in UAE. I just went on to the **glassdoor** and read reviews, the majority of reviews were not very good and some were outrageous to an extent accusing them of non-professionalism and discrimination.

The company is multinational and got this opportunity after hard work.

Now I am confused.

Comment: Just a quick glance it looks like the negative opinions come from Texas after the company(?) branch was acquired by larger and some changes were made. So that may be an indication of people leaving bad reviews after being laid off.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How much stock should I put in negative Glassdoor reviews?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/118686/how-much-stock-should-i-put-in-negative-glassdoor-reviews)

Comment: I think this is largely situational.... how much do you need the job?

Comment: I faced a similar situation, the company was involved in a public scandal and had a number of bad glassdoor reviews. So I brought it up with the interviewer and he explained that the division I was talking to was isolated from the public issues and he encouraged me to ask the other interviewers about it (I did and they agreed that it wasn't an issue). I ultimately didn't accept their offer for other reasons, so I don't know how it would have turned out.

Comment: I wonder why you didn't use Glassdoor before doing any interviews?  It seems a bit backwards to look at reviews after working hard to get in the door.

Comment: I think your financial situation is relevent here.

Comment: Related: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/12516/325

Comment: @Johnny I didn't know about the existence of glassdoor or any reviews site before interviewing, I came to know about it just yesterday.

Answer (score 53):

As with any review site, you're going to experience bad reviews from disgruntled employees/customers.

All you can really do is take a balanced view of what the reviews are actually saying (and judging the mood/motives of the reviewer) and go from there.

Don't forget that you can raise the issue of these bad reviews in your interview and ask what the employer is doing to address those concerns (or whether they have any sensible rebuttal to them).

And accepting an interview doesn't oblige you to take a job with them.

Comment: I think I should give it a hit, join and see what they are upto.

Comment: You're going to learn a lot from an interview if you use the glassdoor reviews as a source of questions.  But don't just quote the reviews verbatim but instead ask questions about the issues they raise (as long as they're not obvious and baseless rantings).

Comment: This was a job offer, not an interview offer...

Comment: Just because you have a job offer doesn't mean you can't talk over further issues before you accept.

Answer (score 38):

If it is a big company, then take glassdoor etc with a grain of salt. At the company where I work, there are business units where I would leave in 10 minutes, however I am happy the team and business unit where I am. Such review are likely to catch opinions of people in specific part of the company with a short turnaround time of the employees, and as such may be biased in one direction or the other.

Comment: "take glassdoor etc with a grain of salt" <- just this.

Answer (score 14):

First, you should check whether glassdoors is known and used in UAE.

For example, in my country, there are other sites which are much more popular. As a result, the reviews on glassdoors are non-representative for the companies I know here (they are actually too good). The reviews on more popular sites are, however, very valuable.

I do read people's opinions on similar sites and I write them too. I've had very good experiences with that:

1. Once I read that a company I applied at expected you to work 12h/day (legally only 8h are allowed in my country. I was offered the position and asked the HR about how much they worked. They confirmed the 12 h. Interestingly, they just told me about it after I asked. So if I hadn't consulted glassdoors, I would have accepted a position that I would have to quit after a few weeks or months. Basically, glassdoors saved my a** - I don't want to come across as a job-hopper.
2. When you read reviews for my previous company, you will see opinions that the atmosphere is horrible and there's a lot of verbal aggression. That was true and that was the reason I quit.
3. I once didn't check glassdoors before an interview. It was the most chaotic interview in my life. I don't want to go into details, but it was simply amazingly disorganized. Anyway, when after the interview I checked the reviews on the equivalent of glassdoors, the dominant opinion was the company was extremely disorganized.

Of course, there might be false reviews. But if you have 10+ different people sharing their opinion, you can normally understand whether there are any big red flags.

Comment: Agree. Reviews should not be the only criteria. But, if a problem comes up repeatedly in reviews, then it is a huge red flag and in my experience the red flags turned out to be real and persistent problems.

Answer (score 8):

People are FAR more likely to complain than they are to compliment.

According to the White House Office of Consumer Affairs.

A dissatisfied customer will tell between 9-15 people about their experience. Around 13% of dissatisfied customers tell more than 20 people while happy customers who get their issue resolved tell about 4-6 people about their experience.

So take any ratings site with a grain of salt.  It is human nature to complain, and with the age of the internet, people have taken this up to 11.  Good reviews don't go viral.  Bad ones do.

Comment: You should also take good reviews with a grain of salt. If you're seeing a lot of positive reviews, then it might mean they're asked to write the review. Especially one sentence ones.

Comment: Glassdoor doesn't have reviews from customers, it has employee reviews.  The customer data is quite tangential.

Comment: @Underminer appropriate name.  I used inductive reasoning to go from the specific customer situation to the general statement of human nature, which is general.  I used the example of customer data to show that people can be as much as 5 times more likely to complain than recommend.

Comment: @RichardU, while I understand your sentiment, I don't see how you arrive from "Dissatisfied customers complain 2-3 times more than satisfied customers compliment" to "Take all review sites with a grain of salt, including Glassdoor".

Comment: @Underminer Simple:   It's inductive reasoning.  Take one thing about human behavior, then apply it to other human behavior.  People complain about customer service, people complain about their jobs.  People complain more about bad service than they speak about good service.  People complain about bad jobs more than they commend good jobs.  What part of this progression escapes you

Comment: @RichardU complaints don't signify untruth

Comment: Squeaky wheel always gets the grease. But it's your job to figure out if they were trying to idiotically add some to a sealed ball bearing or not.

Comment: @Underminer nor did I say that they did.  Let me put this simply, in deference to you.  People are more likely to complain than to praise, therefore you will see an overrepresentation of complaints to compliments.