# Diverse job reviews for a company are too confusing

Tags: work-environment

There are many websites out there that showcases reviews of the ex or current employees of that company. It is natural that a new applicant, like me, would consider the review before deciding for a job switch. It becomes more vital when the job switch requires an expensive migration to newer city/country.

But more I read review of a particular company, the more I get confused. What reviews to believe and what are biased. How to determine? How to judge a workplace from outside without having to work there and blindly believing neither too positive nor too negative reviews.

If everything of that company, including job role, location and their marketed video appeals me but reviews are making me playing a real tug-of-war in my mind.

Comment: See also: [How much stock should I put in negative Glassdoor reviews?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/118686/how-much-stock-should-i-put-in-negative-glassdoor-reviews)

Comment: There's a lot of advice available on how to spot fake reviews. A lot of it will be applicable to Glassdoor reviews as well. Most of that advice is geared toward spotting fake positive reviews but negative reviews that aren't completely honest will use some of the same tactics.